# How to truncate table in sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete

**I am new in android. Can anyone help me to hows truncate table in sqlite in android..
Can anyone give me example of that delete table?
Please help me.**

Comment: There's no `truncate` function in SQLite, so you should go with `delete` w/o `where` clause, as klaustopher suggested.

Comment: According to [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) certain versions may optimize a `DELETE FROM table` with no `WHERE` clause into a truncate operation -- but there is no explicit `TRUNCATE` statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you want to do? If you want to truncate the table (delete all data) you can use the `DELETE` query without a where condition. If you want to delete the entire table you can use a `DROP TABLE` query

Comment: If I use Delete Query then it is deleting all rows but on insertion it starts not from id as 1.

Answer (score 5):

It is the two step process:

1. First delete all data from that table using this:

   Delete from TableName
2. Second step:

   DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name='TableName';